# View of nodes with no taxonomy term

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

How can I create a view of nodes that are not tagged with any taxonomy term? Note, terms will be added in time and I wont be able to update the view each time.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you create a filter for "Content: Has taxonomy term" and then select "Is empty (NULL)" as the operator.